# Lift full types into monad transformers

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I have these 3 monad transformers

```
type T[A] = OptionT[Future, A]
type E[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]
type P[A] = OptionT[E, A]
```

I want to lift the corresponding full types (meaning exact corresponding type) into these. So for T, I want to lift Future[Option[Int]] into it. for E, I want to lift Future(Either[String, Int]) and for P, I want to lift (Future[Either[String, Option[Int]]]) into it.

I wrote this code and it compiles. except that I need a more succinct way of achieving the same thing.

```
val x : T[Int] = OptionT(Future(Option(10)))
val y : E[Int] = EitherT(Future(Right(10).asInstanceOf[Either[String, Int]]))
val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right(Option(10)).asInstanceOf[Either[String, Option[Int]]])))
```

I am using Cats 1.1.0 and Scala 2.12.3.

The asInstanceOf thing is very annoying. but if I change the last line to

```
val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right(Option(10)))))
```

I get this compiler error

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to 
[error] /Users//code/dallasscalacats/src/main/scala/com//Transformers.scala:32: no type parameters for method apply: (value: F[Either[A,B]])cats.data.EitherT[F,A,B] in object EitherT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,Option[Int]]])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,Option[Int]]]
[error]  required: ?F[Either[?A,?B]]
[error]     val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right(Option(10)))))
[error]                              ^
[error] /Users//code/dallasscalacats/src/main/scala/com//Transformers.scala:32: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,Option[Int]]]
[error]  required: F[Either[A,B]]
[error]     val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right(Option(10)))))
[error]                                            ^
[error] /Users//code/dallasscalacats/src/main/scala/com//Transformers.scala:32: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : cats.data.EitherT[F,A,B]
[error]  required: com.abhi.Transformers.E[Option[Int]]
[error]     (which expands to)  cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,Option[Int]]
[error]     val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right(Option(10)))))
[error]                                     ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 11, 2018 9:46:21 PM
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use implicits method of `import cats.implicits._`
then you can write something like

```
val z: P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(10.some.asRight[String])))
```

and of course, You can write your own implicits as well

```
implicit class EitherFuture[A, B](val e: Future[A Either B]) extends AnyVal {
  def asEitherT: EitherT[Future, A, B] = EitherT(e)
}

implicit class OptionEitherT[A](val e: EitherT[Future, String, Option[A]]) extends AnyVal {
  def asOptionT = OptionT(e)
}

val zz: P[Int] = Future(10.some.asRight[String]).asEitherT.asOptionT
```

Comment: very cool! Let's see if there are more answers. otherwise I'm happy to mark this one.

Comment: Make sure to `extend AnyVal` to avoid the extra wrapping allocation of the implicit class.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  thanks for the comment. updated the answer

Comment: I have one last question. everything works fine. but if I do
`for {x <- Future(10.some.asRight[String]).asEitherT.asOptionT} yield {..}` I get an error `value foreach is not a member of cats.data.OptionT`

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch  this is bit off-topic though, `foreach` is equivalent to `for` statement without `yield`.  I could run the code you pasted. so check the syntax of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Try providing type params for Right:

```
val z : P[Int] = OptionT(EitherT(Future(Right[String,Option[Int]](Option(10)))))
```

Without the type parameters, when you do `Right(1)` scala infers `Either[Nothing,Int]`.

Comment: still very verbose. is there no better way?